# Auditing REST API call - Ensuring Salesforce audits

Tags: rest-api, setup-audit-log

I am connecting to Salesforce using Salesforce REST API from a .net application.

The Salesforce team are suggesting that they will build a wrapper around native salesforce api so that, they are able to **implement Auditing** from Salesforce end.

I am wondering, if there is an easier way to Audit all the CRUD operations that was performed by a particular connected app.

What we want to Audit:

- Who accessed via particular connected app?
- What information they
  accessed?
- Time of access

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce has the Event Reporting API which, last time I checked, is an add-on product

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/using_resources_event_log_files.htm

The list of event types that are logged automatically by the platform is here:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_eventlogfile_supportedeventtypes.htm

The Rest API resource contains the User ID and Session Key which you can presumably map back to the Login events

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_eventlogfile_login.htm

I don't know of any way to get the exact record IDs that were accessed aside from building the layer you're suggesting.

Comment: N.B. product is called Shield Event Monitoring